# Keyboard is scaled on iphone 7+

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

I have ported an old app and now using Xcode 8 to compile / run on iphone 7+. Everything is working fine except the keyboard looks scaled up (Larger than standard keyboard as seen in iMessages). 
Attached is the image on iPhone 7+, first one is iMessages screen with its standard keyboard and second screen is my app with scaled up keyboard.

On capturing UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, I see that keyboard size returned is 320x253 on iphone 7+ which is what I also get while running app on iphone 5. Another test app developed in XCode 8 gives keyboard size of 414x226 on iphone 7+ and 320x216 on iphone 5.

It seems somehow the OS is treating my app as iphone 5 compatible only and display keyboard size that's supported by iphone 5.

[iMessages and my app on iphone 7+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSfxj.png)

Comment: Does your app have a proper Launch screen file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a properly sized launch images for all compatible devices. This is a tedious task. Since iOS 8, Apple supports proving a launch interface in the form of a storyboard or a XIB file, which the system uses to generate a launch image. This is the preferred method of supplying a launch image in modern iOS development, unless this pattern specifically does not fit your requirements (a custom launch image that is very specific to the size of the device).

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly